# How can I test that all .dlls required for a .net program are available?

Tags: reflection, dll, c++-cli

I'm trying to test-load all the required .dlls for a C++-CLI program to make sure none are missing, but what looked like a simple method to do this doesn't seem to work:

```
    // First make sure we have all the .dlls we need
    Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly();
    array<System::Reflection::AssemblyName^>^ referencedAssemblies = assembly->GetReferencedAssemblies();
    for each(System::Reflection::AssemblyName^ referencedAssemblyName in referencedAssemblies)
    {
        String^ strName = referencedAssemblyName->Name;
        assembly->Load(strName);
    }
```

...gives me an exception which says `Could not load file or assembly 'System' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
    // First make sure we have all the .dlls we need
    Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly();
    array<System::Reflection::AssemblyName^>^ referencedAssemblies = assembly->GetReferencedAssemblies();
    for each(System::Reflection::AssemblyName^ referencedAssemblyName in referencedAssemblies)
    {
        assembly->Load( referencedAssemblyName );
    }
```

Didn't need the intermediate string in there :-)